# Sass adding host to image-path helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I have something like the following in a bunch of `.scss` files:

```
image-path("some/image/i/only/want/the/dang/path.of")
```

Which compiles fine in the `development` env:

```
# rake assets:precompile
"/assets/some/image/i/only/want/the/dang/path.of"
```

But when compiling `production` I get:

```
# RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
"https://dumd-cdn-I-dont-want.com/assets/some/image/i/only/want/the/dang/path.of"
```

It's gotta be something in my `production.rb` file, but the thing is I do want the asset host for other things:

```
config.asset.host = "https://dumd-cdn-I-dont-want.com/"
```

The thing is I just expect the dang `asset-path` helper to, I don't know, just give me the path and move on from there.

Why oh why oh why is it not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is desired behavior: https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/355